# methods after extending abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance

I don't know exacly how to describe my problem so I'll make an example:

```
public abstract class A {

  public abstract void methodToOverride();
  public void methodNotToOverride() { }

}

public class B extends A {

  @Override
  public void methodToOverride() { }
  public void someOtherMethodNotFromClassA() { }

}
```

now I need to do such thing in my code:

```
A object = new B();
object.someOtherMethodNotFromClassA();
```

but I get "Cannot resolve method error". Defining such method in the abstract class is not an option. Any clue?

Comment: `class` is a keyword in Java. you can't use it as a (variable) identifier.

Comment: I made it in hurry, sorry for the syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. While the object is of type B, the reference is of type A. Therefore, you are only able to access methods visible to class A.

If you change this:

```
A a = new B();
```

to this:

```
B a = new B();
```

you would be able to access `someOtherMethodNotFromClassA`. Another option would be to cast `a` to type `B`:

```
A a = new B();
((B)a).someOtherMethodNotFromClassA();
```

Comment: Well... that's it, I had a blackout or sth and couldn't figure it myself, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Despite, that there are some other syntax errors, Oliver Weiler is right, the Reference is of type A, thus you can only access methods of the type A.

If you cast it to type B, then you could also access methods of type B. To go safe, check, if the type really is B with `instanceof`

```
A clazz = new B();
if (clazz instanceof B)
  ((B)clazz).someOtherMethodNotFromClassA();
```

I believe your real code is a bit more complex, thus you may think about casting ...

And btw: a variable name 'class' wont work, use somethign different.

Comment: `class` is actually a name the compiler won't let you use. Most people use `clazz` instead, to identify a `Class` object.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need to use the method from class `B`, and *really* need to specify if by using the abstract superclass `A`, you can use:

```
A clazz = new B();
((B)clazz).someOtherMethodNotFromClassA();
```

Please notice that's not a very good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues in your code.

First, you need to actually provide an implementation for any abstract methods for your class to be instantiable.  So in your case:

```
@Override
public void methodToOverride(){
// does nothing
}
```

Secondly, and more importantly, when you instantiate an object as type `A`, only the methods pertaining to `A` are accessible.  Since, you define `new B()` as type `A`, you will not have access to the method `someOtherMethodNotFromClassA`.

If you want access to it, you need to either instantiate it as a class B, or cast it as a Class B:

```
B someClass = new B();
someClass.someOtherMethodNotFromClassA();
```

or

```
A someClass = new B();
((B)someClass).someOtherMethodNotFromClassA();
```

But keep in mind that latter option is pretty ugly and not easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I just came upon this problem myself and this is horrible! How are you supposed to create reusable code if you cannot make subclasses to be used as arguments? e.g. in a library:

```
public abstract class AbstractSetting {
    private boolean property = false;
    public void getProperty() { return property; }
}

public abstract class AbstractFoo {
    protected AbstractSetting setting;

    protected void setSetting(AbstractSetting setting) {
        this.setting = setting;
    }

    public boolean foo() {
        setting.getProperty();
    }
}
```

Then in application:

```
public class Setting extends AbstractSetting {
    private boolean extraProperty = false;
    public void getExtraProperty() { return extraProperty; }
}

public class Foobar extends AbstractFoo {
    public void foobar() {
        setting.getProperty();
        setting.getExtraProperty();   // CAN'T RESOLVE !
    }
}

Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setSetting(new Setting());
foo.foobar();
```

How does one work around this?

Comment: Well to answer my own question, I figured out adding `property` to the subclass, overriding `setSetting` and and calling `super.setSetting`. But what a kludge. You would think you could just override `property` with a new type. But that doesn't work. You get null error on any method in the abstract class.